# PHP Array problem

Tags: php

```
array(
   array('codcentrocustos' => 1, 'codparent' => null, 'name' => 'lorem ipsum'),
   array('codcentrocustos' => 2, 'codparent' => 1, 'name' => 'lorem ipsum1'),
   array('codcentrocustos' => 3, 'codparent' => 1, 'name' => 'lorem ipsum2'),
   array('codcentrocustos' => 4, 'codparent' => 2, 'name' => 'lorem ipsum3'),
   array('codcentrocustos' => 5, 'codparent' => 3, 'name' => 'lorem ipsum4'),
   array('codcentrocustos' => 6, 'codparent' => null, 'name' => 'lorem ipsum5'),
);
```

Hey guys, i have this array, i need to transform it into an json, but i didnt have anyproblem at this point. The problem its related to what the php its making with it when its needed.

if i try to do an var_dump on he, he return it to me:

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      'codcentrocustos' => int 1
      'codparent' => null
      'name' => string 'lorem ipsum' (length=11)
  1 => 
    array
      'codcentrocustos' => int 2
      'codparent' => int 1
      'name' => string 'lorem ipsum1' (length=12)
  2 => 
    array
      'codcentrocustos' => int 3
      'codparent' => int 1
      'name' => string 'lorem ipsum2' (length=12)
  3 => 
    array
      'codcentrocustos' => int 4
      'codparent' => int 2
      'name' => string 'lorem ipsum3' (length=12)
  4 => 
    array
      'codcentrocustos' => int 5
      'codparent' => int 3
      'name' => string 'lorem ipsum4' (length=12)
  5 => 
    array
      'codcentrocustos' => int 6
      'codparent' => null
      'name' => string 'lorem ipsum5' (length=12)
```

The problem its that i need my array without these refference numbers as

```
array
  **0 =>** 
    array
      'codcentrocustos' => int 1
      'codparent' => null
      'name' => string 'lorem ipsum' (length=11)
  **1 =>**
```

Comment: You can't have the array without the reference numbers! If you tell us exactly where the problem is, maybe we can help with a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert your array to JSON just use [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php). You don't need any sort of conversion.

```
$test = array(
   array('codcentrocustos' => 1, 'codparent' => null, 'name' => 'lorem ipsum'),
   array('codcentrocustos' => 2, 'codparent' => 1, 'name' => 'lorem ipsum1'),
   array('codcentrocustos' => 3, 'codparent' => 1, 'name' => 'lorem ipsum2'),
   array('codcentrocustos' => 4, 'codparent' => 2, 'name' => 'lorem ipsum3'),
   array('codcentrocustos' => 5, 'codparent' => 3, 'name' => 'lorem ipsum4'),
   array('codcentrocustos' => 6, 'codparent' => null, 'name' => 'lorem ipsum5'),
);

print json_encode($test);
```

**Output**

```
[{"codcentrocustos":1,
     "codparent":null,
     "name":"lorem ipsum"},
    {"codcentrocustos":2,
     "codparent":1,
     "name":"lorem ipsum1"},
    {"codcentrocustos":3,
     "codparent":1,
     "name":"lorem ipsum2"},
    {"codcentrocustos":4,
     "codparent":2,
     "name":"lorem ipsum3"},
    {"codcentrocustos":5,
     "codparent":3,
     "name":"lorem ipsum4"},
    {"codcentrocustos":6,
     "codparent":null,
     "name":"lorem ipsum5"}]
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP needs to store the items under some key and by default it uses consecutive integer keys starting with 0. When it shows you the contents of the array it also prints the keys for your convenience (because `var_dump` is a debugging function).

You can simply ignore them and work with the array as if it didn't have them and use the functions: `array_push`, `array_pop`, `array_shift`, `array_unshift`, `next`, `previous`, `current`, etc. to traverse and access the array.

Answer (score 1):

When you create an array like:

```
array(
   array('codcentrocustos' => 1, 'codparent' => null, 'name' => 'lorem ipsum'),
   array('codcentrocustos' => 2, 'codparent' => 1, 'name' => 'lorem ipsum1'),
   array('codcentrocustos' => 3, 'codparent' => 1, 'name' => 'lorem ipsum2'),
   array('codcentrocustos' => 4, 'codparent' => 2, 'name' => 'lorem ipsum3'),
   array('codcentrocustos' => 5, 'codparent' => 3, 'name' => 'lorem ipsum4'),
   array('codcentrocustos' => 6, 'codparent' => null, 'name' => 'lorem ipsum5'),
);
```

if you don't specify a key for the array (like you are doing for the first dimension) what you are really saying is:

```
array(
   0 => array('codcentrocustos' => 1, 'codparent' => null, 'name' => 'lorem ipsum'),
   1 => array('codcentrocustos' => 2, 'codparent' => 1, 'name' => 'lorem ipsum1'),
   2 => array('codcentrocustos' => 3, 'codparent' => 1, 'name' => 'lorem ipsum2'),
   3 => array('codcentrocustos' => 4, 'codparent' => 2, 'name' => 'lorem ipsum3'),
   4 => array('codcentrocustos' => 5, 'codparent' => 3, 'name' => 'lorem ipsum4'),
   5 => array('codcentrocustos' => 6, 'codparent' => null, 'name' => 'lorem ipsum5'),
);
```

If you want them to be different than those numbers, assign a value to the key. If a key is not specified, php assigns one which is usually the highest numeric key +1.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get away from from those indexes. Every element in an array MUST have a key. It's utterly unavoidable.